# Why is this the inverse of an nxn identity matrix plus an nxn upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In class a few weeks we were told that about the inverse of $(I + N)$ is $(I - N + N^2 - \cdots)$ where $I$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix and $N$ is an $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix with zeroes on the diagonal. We were told that this comes from elementary level math, "As we know from 5th grade..." so I don't feel comfortable asking the professor about it. Anyway where is this coming from? I do have a good deal of undergrad and grad level math (I just got into graduate school for math starting January) but I got a very sub-bar K-12 math education so some basics totally allude me to this day.

Comment: Also note N is a NilPotent matrix.

Comment: To answer the question behind the question: We lecturers say things like "As we know from 5th grade" in order to connect to existing knowledge in students' long-term memories, not in order to outlaw questions. That said, I, too, was confused the first time I realized that some of my students were unaware of $a^k-b^k = \left(a-b\right)\left(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+a^{k-3}b^2+\cdots+b^{k-1}\right)$.

Comment: *I got a very sub-bar K-12 math education so some basics totally allude me to this day.* You mean *sub-par*. A sub-bar is a table with a long sandwich that catering brings you. You also mean *elude*. Allude means something totally different.  I can understand how you'd be reluctant to ask, but in a case like this I'd advise trying anyway, at least during a private office hour meeting. It's not like it'll take him/her long to explain, it it would probably be beneficial for the instructor to know where you're at.  Being too anxious to talk to your instructor is a great recipe to do badly.

Comment: "We lecturers say things like "As we know from 5th grade" in order to connect to existing knowledge in students' long-term memories, not in order to outlaw questions." the road to hell is paved with good intentions. Maybe if you really want to use that phrase for that effect consider if it has some other effects? Maybe it's worth it but seems like something worthy of scientific investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $N$ is *nilpotent*, i.e., when computing the powers $N^2$, $N^3$, and so on, the upper triangle gets smaller and smaller until we find that $N^n$ is zero (and so are all higher powers). With this in mind,
$$ (I+N)(I-N+N^2-N^3\pm\cdots \pm N^n)=(I-N+N^2\mp\cdots +(-1)^n N^n)+N(I-N+N^2\mp\cdots +(-1)^n N^n)=(I-N+N^2\mp\cdots +(-1)^n N^n)+(N-N^2\pm\cdots +(-1)^n N^{n+1})=I$$
because all other summands cancel in pairs (apart from $N^{n+1}$ which is zero anyway)

Answer (score 0):

"As we know from fifth grade" should not be taken literally. What is alluded to is a formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series:
$$
1 - r + r^2 -r^3 + r^4 - \cdots = \frac 1 {1+r}
$$
if $|r|<1.$
Maybe most people encounter that in high school.

The extent to which it can be applied to matrices is more complicated than $|r|<1.$ However, note that
\begin{align}
& (I+N) (I - N + N^2 - N^3 + N^4 - \cdots) \\[8pt]
= {} & I(I - N + N^2 - N^3 + N^4 - \cdots) \\
& {} +N(I - N + N^2 - N^3 + N^4 - \cdots) \\[8pt]
= {} & I - N + N^2 - N^3 + N^4 - \cdots \\
& \phantom{I}{} + N - N^2 + N^3 - N^4 + N^5 - \cdots
\end{align}
In the last row, one could say that each term cancels the one above it, so the sum is $I.$ That is problematic since questions of convergence are involved. In particular, what would happen with numbers with absolute values exceeding $1$ were there instead of matrices? To think about convergence one must first consider a finite sequence:
\begin{align}
& I - N + N^2 - N^3 + N^4 - \cdots \pm N^k \\
& \phantom{I} {} + N - N^2 + N^3 - N^4 + \cdots \mp N^k \pm N^{k+1} \\[12pt]
= {} & I \pm N^{k+1}
\end{align}
and then ask whether $N^{k+1}\to0$ as $k\to\infty.$

Comment: I appreciate the insight about the geometric series. However a comment on this statement.
" "As we know from fifth grade" should not be taken literally ... Maybe most people encounter that in high school."
I can tell you, without a doubt, that by a large margin most people do not encounter geometric series unless they go to college. At least not in the united states. And if it's not to be taken literally that we would have encountered this in 5th grade than it is some sort of exaggeration which not all (and I would guess most) students will take that way. Perhaps it's not helpful to say?

Comment: @AlgebraisAwesome : I think it was a rhetorical exaggeration intended only to mean that it's something more elementary than the main topic and that you would be expected to have seen earlier. When I said "most people", I meant most who actually followed the curriculum of math courses offered in high school rather than only those that all pupils are required to take.

Comment: Yeah....your high school experience perhaps wasn't indicative of most people's high school experience? In my school pre-calc (where maybe you'd see geometric series the 1st time) wasn't offered to most students at all because most students didn't get enough education to reach pre-calc. But education past the bare minimum to work a field, factory, service job, or consume pop-media is highly exclusive on this planet. In contrast this forum is mostly folks from richer countries or at least richer social-classes and I suspect this dilutes the perspectives on here and in math academia...

Comment: Whether such a thing is provided to _must_ high-school pupils seems neither here nor there; rather the relevant question is whether it is provided to those who want to learn it. $\qquad$

Comment: I guess we just have different experiences. I went to high school with all kinds of students who wanted to learn but had a ton of obstacles in front of them (including me). Reducing the level of math education in the u.s. (or the globe) to "do these kids want it enough?" ignores the the material reality of their lives. Maybe in a very privileged community you can deduce that "the students have more than enough opportunity to learn what they want" but that's not most peoples circumstances.