# Solving $A^n=Id$ for $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix, Id the identity matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find all solutions to $ A^n =I$ ultimately, for n a positive integer, for $I$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix, A an $n \times n$ matrix over the Complexes.
I would appreciate if , together with the general solution to A^n =I, to see the simpler solution for the case n=2, i.e., the solution to A^2 =I.
I know that ,geometrically, a solution to $A^n =I$ is given  by a  matrix describing a rotation by $ 2 \pi /n$

More specifically, rather than grinding out products of matrices and solving systems of equations,  I'm interested in the approach of factoring $0=A^2 -I=(A+I)(A-I)$, or an equivalent factorization for $A^-I$, finding the kernel of both $(A+I)$, i.e., the set(subspace) of v with  , as well as the "left kernel" of $A-I$ , so that (A+I)v =0 , as well as the left subspace w of (A-I) with w(A+I)=0
w(A-I) are solutions.

I'm aware that under some conditions, A may be nilpotent, so that we can use
so that we may use the [method of factoring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407358/why-is-this-the-inverse-of-an-nxn-identity-matrix-plus-an-nxn-upper-triangular-m)

As  $$A^k -I =(A-I)(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}+\cdots+A+I )$$

But my A is not necessarily nilpotent. Are there "nice" ways to describe the above kernels of $(A+I), (A-I)$ respectively?

Comment: How can $A$ be nilpotent if $A^2$ has full rank? And what is $k$? If $A^2= I$ then $A^{2m}= I$ and $A^{2m+1}= A$ (for every integer  $m\ge 1$).

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I was trying to explain why the linked solution did not work. sorry, k is a positive integer.

Comment: A matrix such that $A^k=I$ for *any* $k\gt 0$ cannot be nilpotent. A nilpotent matrix satisfies $A^m=0$ for some $m$. If you had both things, then raising $A^k$ to a suitable power you would get $0=I$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : yes, I agree, I was ( arguably poorly) trying to point that. I get that $A^k x = \lambda ^k x$, so that if A were nilpotent, we would need $0$ as eigenvalue.   , for eigenvalues \lambda. I was just trying to document that I had been through some related posts.

Comment: Your "geometric" solution is incorrect. If $A^2=I$, then $A$ cannot be a rotation by $2\pi/n$ unless $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Thank you, I just edited,

Comment: So what's with the downvote?

Comment: You seem to be changing the problem now. Are you assuming *both* $A^2=I$ and $A^n=I$, or are you assuming just one of them? Is now the second condition tied to the size of the matrix? It wasn't before. Changing the problem so fundamentally, silently (no indication in the text that you changed the problem) may attract downvotes on answers that were correct when posted, but now address a different problem.

Comment: @MSIS I downvoted this. There are too many corrections and backtracks here. It is on the person writing the question to be clear!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : I have the bad habit to assume others can read my mind, that I'm trying to change. Apologies, and edited again.

Comment: @Mike: Fair -enough. I have the bad habit of assuming others can read my mind when I write, so I cut corners. Trying to change that.

Comment: I don't see an edit. Your most recent edit was on 2022-11-17 21:23:09Z; to the comment to which you replied is from 2022-11-17 21:34:30Z, about eleven minutes later.  Your reply saying you had edited again is from 2022-11-17 21:47:47Z, but no edits have been made. The current version **is** what I'm complaining about.

Comment: I'm also having serious problems connecting, ad connection falls periodically every few minutes,, so edits dont go through..

Comment: So don't say you edited until you actually edited.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Let A be a square matrix. Is there a " nice " way of finding the kernels of A-I, i.e., $\{x: (A-I)x=0\}$, and the " right kernel" : $\{y: y(A-I)=0\}$ ? My motivation is that such x,y would satisfy $(A-I)(A+I)=0$. Just curious how this approach would bear out.

Comment: I do not understand your stated "motivation". But the nonzero vectors $x$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ are precisely the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$; you find them by solving the system $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$, usually via Gaussian elimination. The same can be done with the $y$ (which, honestly, I would call the **left** kernel, not the "right" kernel), by finding the eigenvectors of $A^t$ corresponding to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** This answer was posted when the problem read

> I'm trying to find all solutions to $A^2 =I ; A^k =I$, for $I$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix, A an $n \times n$ matrix over the Complexes.

It is unclear if this is still the question being asked.

---

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(t-1)(t+1)$, so the characteristic polynomial splits, all its eigenvalues are either $1$ or $-1$, and the matrix is diagonalizable.

If $k$ is odd, then $-1$ cannot be an eigenvalue (as then you would have $(-1)^k$ an eigenvalue of $A^k = I$), so in this case, $A=I$.

If $k$ is even, then your possibilities are just the $n+1$ different choices with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, so you would get, up to similarity, diagonal matrices with $k$ entries equal to $1$ and $n-k$ entries equal to $-1$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.

---

The problem has now changed substantially. In any case: if a matrix satisfies $A^n=I$ over the complex numbers, then its minimal polynomial divides $t^n-1$, and therefore splits and is square free, so $A$ is diagonalizable, and its eigenvalues must be $n$th roots of unity.

If $n=2$ and $A$ is $2\times 2$, you have three possibilities, up to similarity:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1\end{array}\right),\qquad \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right),\qquad\text{and}\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cr}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right).$$

For $n\gt 2$, the solutions are, up to similarity, the matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\zeta_n^{k_1}& 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & \zeta_n^{k_2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \zeta_n^{k_n}
\end{array}\right)$$
where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive comples $n$th root of unity, and $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ are integers satisfying
$0\leq k_1\leq\cdots\leq k_n\lt n$. Every such matrix satisfies $A^n = I$, and every matrix that satisfies $A^n=I$ is similar to a matrix of this form, and different choices of $(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ yield non-similar matrices. Therefore, there are as many possibilities (up to similarity) as there are ways to make $n$ choices with repetition from among $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, which is $\binom{2n-1}{n}$. For example, when $n=2$ we get $\binom{3}{2}=3$ possibilities (up to similarity).

Comment: Eigenvals can be any $k$th roots of unity, not just real ones

Comment: @JMP: Not if it also satisfies $A^2=I$. The given matrix satisfies *both* $A^k=I$ **and** $A^2=I$.

Comment: Ah, I understood $k$ as a generalization of $2$

Comment: @JMP Apparently, you were able to read the OPs mind where I was not.

Comment: My mind is not an easy place to read. Ask my therapist ;). Thanks, Arturo.